# Does google maps gadget work on a page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a page using jQuery UI Accordion and some jQuery script language.  I tried adding the Google Maps and driving directions gadget to this page and ran into some problems.  On IE v9, the gadget doesn't displays correctly and is unusable.  Seems to work fine in FF or Chrome.

Is there a known issue between the JQ and Google Maps libraries.  I'm pretty new to jQuery but know I could try using .noConflict.  I'd rather know that there's a library issue before trying.

I looked around for conflict issues at jQuery forum and here but can't seem to find much about it.  Mostly see questions using jQuery mobile and Google Maps.

Does anyone know of this issue, or can explain what the problem is.  I'm trying to learn and need some guidance on this one.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: i don't know about any particular conflict, and I often use these 2 technology toghether. Can you please provide some more detail about your problem? You could post your code here or provide a link to a jsFiddle that demonstrate the problem...

Comment: Hi, I ran into same problem but the problem was that there was a conflict when I used jQuery from google hosting. Try to include jQuery from your own source. See this http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/01/google-maps-part-2-implementing-driving.html

Comment: Arvind, I am using my own source. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have no experience with the Gadget, but I suspect it's just an `iframe` embed. This should definitely work with jQuery on the page.

If you'd like more control over the map you're displaying, I'd highly recommend using the [Google Maps Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Comment: If it is an iframe and you're loading the map into a hidden div, there could be a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084363/google-maps-in-hidden-div

Comment: The script is in a hidden div, but it doesn't run until an address is entered by the user.  I'm not sure why it works fine in FF and Chrome, but not IE9?  I think I'll take it out of the hidden div and see if it works.  Then I'll know if that's the problem or not.  Thanks.

Comment: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/gadgets/directions/
Was hoping to use a simple gadget, not because I'm lazy, I'm just pretty new to JS and jQuery.

Comment: I moved the google script out of the hidden div and it started working fine.  I have read about google scripts needing coordinates and therefore won't run in a hidden div, but I didn't realize that meant load as well.  Dumb on my part I guess.  Thanks everyone for the help. Dave