# Google map gray box in a hidden div in react js

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I tried the solution here [Google maps in hidden div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084363/google-maps-in-hidden-div) but it didn't work. Think it might be an issue with react. The map loads fine when not placed in the hidden div.

When state.hideScore turns false in the parent container, the map shows up but as a gray box. any help?

Parent container

```
<div hidden={this.state.hideScore}>         
<ScoreExplanation score={this.state.score} />
<br />
<ResultList data={this.state.scoreArray} />     
<ResultMap />           
</div>
```

Component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

var $ = require ('jquery');
var map;

var ResultMap = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    // ** Instantiating the Map ** //
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 14
        });

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={{overflow:'visible',height:'300px',width:'300px'}} id="map"></div>
    );
  }
});
export default ResultMap;
```

Comment: when you activate the hide div  ... you should call (or recall ) or initialize the map ... is not an issue with react is for all js .. try build a initialize function you can call when show the div  ... I don't know react so ... i can shhow you the code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing the map in `componentDidMount`, you should instead initialize it when the parent re-renders after calling `setState` to change `this.state.hideScore`. What's happening right now is, your map is getting loaded into the ResultMap component before its parent is visible. You should instead wait until the parent component is visible, then instantiate the ResultMap.

Example:

Parent component render method

```
// I prefer using CSS classes to hide/display components.
// Initialize hideScore to 'hidden' and see CSS.
render () {
  return (
    <div className={this.state.hideScore}>         
      <ScoreExplanation score={this.state.score} />
      <br />
      <ResultList data={this.state.scoreArray} />     
      <div id='result-container'></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Parent component click handler method (Can be whatever method).

```
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    hideScore: 'shown' // See CSS.
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ResultMap />,
    document.getElementById('result-container')
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.shown {
  display: block; // Or whatever is your preference.
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Although I had to remove the curly braces in ReactDOM.render for it to work.

Comment: Not sure why I had those in there. Good catch!