# Google map not showing in hidden wordpress tab using Geomywp shortcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, tabs

I'm using Geomywp. I am using the following shortcode in a hidden tab (tab number 5): `[gmw_member_location map_width=100%]`

When the user clicks the hidden tab the map loads empty. If the user then resizes the browser window the map appears.

If I put the shortcode in the first tab that loads initially, the map loads just fine.

It seems that this question is similar but it isn’t working since its meant for WP Job Manager Geolocation: `https://geomywp.com/forums/topic/map-wont-show-on-hidden-tab`

It seems to suggest that something needs to be added to `initialise/refresh` the map upon clicking the tab. If that's the case does anyone know **how I can re-initialise the map on clicking the tab?**

**Is there any way to fix this?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know Google Maps have problem with rendering inside hidden elements. This bothered me a few months ago and this post helped me out: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084363/google-maps-in-hidden-div)